# selected value of WPF combobox does not display

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, wpf-controls

I have an xml file as follows :-

```
<Root>
   <Level>
       <id>1</id>
       <display>Level1</display>
   </Level>
   <Level>
       <id>2</id>
       <display>Level2</display>
   </Level>
</Root>
```

and I have a WPF combobox :-

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbLevel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="73,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"
       SelectedValuePath="id" SelectedValue="{Binding XPath=/Root/Level/id}" 
       ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/Root/Level}"
       IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

The insert and display works well, however the problem is when I want to populate this combobox with a selected value.

At the moment I have the following

```
private void InitCombo(XDocument xdoc, ComboBox comboBox, string NodeName)
{
    var displayItems = from ele in xdoc.Descendants(NodeName)
    select new
    {
         id = (string)ele.Element("id"),
         display = (string)ele.Element("display")
    };            

    comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "display";
    comboBox.SelectedValuePath = "id";
    comboBox.ItemsSource = displayItems.ToList();
 }
```

and then I am adding the selected value as follows:

```
cmbLevel.SelectedValue = level;
```

Do I need to add anything else for it to show the selected value in my combobox? Do I need to rebind the combobox?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: What are you trying to set as the selected value?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be somewhat confused about using the `ComboBox` selection options. I would advise you to read the [How to: Use SelectedValue, SelectedValuePath, and SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788714.aspx) page at MSDN for help. There are a number of ways to make selection in a `ComboBox`, all of which are clearly described in the linked article.

> From MSDN:
>
> DisplayMemberPath:  Gets or sets a path to a value on the source object to serve as the visual representation of the object.
>
> SelectedValue:  Gets or sets the value of the SelectedItem, obtained by using SelectedValuePath.
>
> SelectedValuePath:  Gets or sets the path that is used to get the SelectedValue from the SelectedItem.
>
> SelectedItem:  Gets or sets the first item in the current selection or returns null if the selection is empty

Also, why are you setting the same properties in code *and* in XAML?

Comment: Sheridan, I am quite new to WPF, that is why I am doing this sample application.  I binded the SelectedValue in code as well as in XAML, since when I had it in XAML only, it still was not getting the selectedValue correctly

Comment: Also I need to set the ID in the code since its not being set in the XAML once I load my object. Isn't that the case?  I come from an ASP.NET background, maybe that's what behind my thinking